# Scroll Down Arrow CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would really appreciate a little help with the CSS below. I have this implemented on www.thehomebird.com The problem I'm experiencing is that if I change the size of the browser window (horizontally) the arrow moves with that size which means if i use different browsers it's always in the wrong place. In perfect world I would love to have it act as if I change the size of the browser it always stays at the same place.

When clicked it goes down as it does now and disspaears. When you scroll up it shows up again. I tried to find some websites where I saw it act as it should like but cant find aything at the moment Ill add it here when see it again, meanwhile hopefully someone knows what Im trying to do and could help me. Thank you in advance!

```
`/* Middle screen Arrow */


.scroll_down_button {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    display: inline-block;
    font: 400 20px/1 "Josefin Sans",sans-serif;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 50%;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-decoration: none;
    top: 75%;
    transform: translate(0px, -50%);
    transition: opacity 1s ease 0s;
    z-index: 999;
    outline: none !important;
}

.click_able_arrow {
     animation: 3s ease 0s normal none infinite running sdb04;
     border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
     border-left: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
     box-sizing: border-box;
     height: 24px;
     left: 50%;
     margin-left: -12px;
     position: absolute;
     vertical-align:middle;
     top: 75%;
     transform: rotate(-45deg);
     width: 24px;
}


 @-webkit-keyframes sdb04 {
 0% {
     -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, 0);
 }
 20% {
     -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-10px, 10px);
 }
 40% {
     -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, 0);
 }
}

@keyframes sdb04 {
0% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, 0);
}
20% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-10px, 10px);
}
40% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, 0);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please fiddle it out the same?

Comment: I guess this would be agood site example https://www.bukwild.com/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question? The arrow is changing its position when the browser window is resized? .... might first thoughts is you are positioning it with

```
left: 50%;
```

which means if the screen gets bigger it will move, I would generally use some thing like

```
left: 50vw;
```

for that anyway.

but if you dont want it to move from a fixed location have you tried defining its posistion like

```
left: 200px;
```

and instead of absolute

```
position: fixed;
```

this might work too?

```
left: 50%; 
position: fixed;
```

but I'm not sure...

Comment: Ill try all the suggestions and report back , my original post wasnt really that clear.

Comment: ok no thats not working now the arrow moves with me when i scroll down with mouse, I want arrow to stay only on the main screen at the bottom of the video no matter how wide or narrow i have the browser window.. Does that make sense?

Comment: okay ...if you use position: absolute; but define it in left: 200px; does that get the desired result?

Comment: checking..left and right is ok at 50% its more about top-

Comment: I made some adjustments

Comment: yeah its not perfect but it will do i guess, i played with top / bottom - its hard to explain this when im not showing it live on the screen..thanks for your help anyways!

Answer (score 0):

I made some adjustments:

removed vertical-align:middle; (in both sections .scroll_down_button and .click_able_arrow )

removed top: 75%; in .click_able_arrow

and added 550px instead of 75% in .scroll_down_button

still not perfect but better i guess

/* Middle screen Arrow */

```
.scroll_down_button {
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
display: inline-block;
font: 400 20px/1 "Josefin Sans",sans-serif;
margin: 0 auto;
left: 50%;
letter-spacing: 0.1em;
opacity: 1;
position: absolute;
text-decoration: none;
top: 550px;
transform: translate(0px, -50%);
transition: opacity 1s ease 0s;
z-index: 999;
outline: none !important;
}

.click_able_arrow {
animation: 3s ease 0s normal none infinite running sdb04;
border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
border-left: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
box-sizing: border-box;
height: 24px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -12px;
position: absolute;
transform: rotate(-45deg);
width: 24px;
}
```